# Array inside array doesnt show value of database preparement

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I try to create circle and get data for that from database. But it doesnt show values, It prints bindings.

```
function circle()
    {

        $sql = "SELECT count(projects.id) AS count, projects.status as status
                FROM user_projects
                    INNER JOIN projects ON projects.id = user_projects.project_id
                WHERE user_projects.user_id = :user_id
                AND projects.workspace = :current_workspace
                GROUP BY projects.status";


        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $this->id, ':current_workspace' => $this->userinfo['current_workspace']));
        //$stmt->debugDumpParams();
        $projectProcess = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        //print_r($projectProcess);

        $total = $this->totalProjects();

        $arrProcessLable= [];
        $arrProcessPer = [];
        foreach ($projectProcess as $lable => $process){
            $arrProcessLable[]= $lable;
            $arrProcessPer[] = round(($process*100)/$total,2);
        }

        $arrProcessClass = ['text-success','text-primary','text-danger'];

        return ['a' => $arrProcessLable, 'b' => $arrProcessPer, 'c' => $arrProcessClass];
    }
```

Array prints "count" not value like 6 or something.
It should print 6 project.id count.

Also samething it prints "status" not like "Ongoing" or "Hold", "Finished"
It should print 6 projects "Ongoing"

Arry:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [0] => count
            [1] => status
        )

    [b] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 0
        )

    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => text-success
            [1] => text-primary
            [2] => text-danger
        )

)
```

Comment: Could you explain this part a little bit more? What do you mean by *"it doesnt show values, It prints bindings."*?

Comment: @Dharman it should be array( [a] => array ( [0] => 6 [1] => "Ongoing"...

Comment: Then what is the purpose of your foreach loop? Just return the original `$projectProcess` without the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch each row individually.  In other words you need to call `fetch()` in a loop to access each row (alternatively, you could `fetchAll()`, but that is not appropriate if you intend to iterate/process the data on the same "layer" of the script).

See this reference: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/fetch_modes#FETCH_OBJ

You are iterating the properties and values within a single row.  However, you should be iterating the rows and manually accessing the values by property name.

Untested suggestion:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
    $arrProcessLable[] = $row->status;
    $arrProcessPer[] = round(($row->count * 100) / $total, 2);
}
```

---

Additional notes:

- You don't need to alias `projects.status as status` because the column `projects.status` will be given the property `status` in the result set anyhow -- the table names are omitted.
- MySQL has suitable mathematical functions that would permit you to perform all calculations before php touches the result set. This may be something of interest for you.
- Lastly, if you only want to fetch once `->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)` looks like something useful, since you are pairing statuses with their counts.  Refer to the above link and scroll down.